# How can I deploy a Camel Route on JBoss Fuse?

Tags: maven, jboss, apache-camel, jbossfuse

I've developed a camel route in a Fuse Project using blueprint, now I would like to deploy the route in the Fuse Server.

I'm not sure if this is a problem but the blueprint.xml returns me this error

> White spaces are required between publicId and systemId at line 1

I've tried deploying the project following some guides online: tried to use  drag and drop function in jboss dev studio dragging the project folder into server window but nothing happened.

Also tried use maven building and deploying as a maven project via osgi:install but it returns me this error :

> Error executing command: Error installing bundles:    Unable to start bundle file:/home/pajarittu/jboss_workspace/prova_sub/target/camel-subscribe-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar: Unresolved constraint in bundle camel-subscribe [293]: Unable to resolve 293.0: missing requirement [293.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.json)`

Do you know how to solve this problems or different ways to deploy the service? thanks in advance for the the answers.

Comment: If you use any camel components you likely need to install them first with features:install camel-xxx, where xxx is the component name. The name can be seen here: http://camel.apache.org/components.html

Answer (score 1):

First of all I recommend looking at this blog post:
http://lhein.blogspot.de/2014/07/improved-server-adapters-for-jboss-fuse.html
I described there how the deployment works now in tooling.

Then you should also make sure that if you choose Fuse 6.1 you can't use Java 8 to run it. I think the last error you posted exactly is caused by this. (I could be wrong though ;) )

Finally Claus is right. If you want to run Camel on Fuse runtime you should make sure you installed all the needed features / camel components in order to sucessfully run your routes.

Hope that helps,
Lars

Comment: I love the JBoss Fuse tooling. Great work guys. I have spent many hours in that tool and it is spot on for my needs. Currently using Camel for a IOT project and it has been a wonderful experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at an example which used camel , REST and camel route is deployed on JBOSS fuse 6.1

https://github.com/TheMaheshBiradar/fuse-middlware-services

.